# SharePoint 2013 -creating site collection with CMSPUBLISHING#0 template fails

Tags: site-collection, site-template, uls

Wondering whether anyone can shed any light as to how to troubleshoot this issue. I can't seem to create a new site collection with CMSPUBLISHING#0 template - command shown below. Running into this issue in more than one farm both has SharePoint 2013 SP1 applied. Can create site collection with another publishing template from Central Admin (BLANKINTERNET#0). Log shows it creates the site collection but when it tries to apply the site template it runs into the below error and rolls back changes.

I've updated full ULS log filtered by the correlation ID [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1jcczJaToU3bDRHR0VvYUJPTWc&authuser=0) - if anyone is interested.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
New-SPSite http://WebAppURL/divisions/SiteCollec -OwnerAlias "domain\User" -Name "Group Office" -Template "CMSPUBLISHING#0" -ContentDatabase "DB_SiteCollec"
**New-SPSite : The web being updated was changed by an external process**.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SPSite http://WebAppURL/divisions/SiteCollec -OwnerAlias ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletNewSite:SPCmdletNewSite) [New-SPSite], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSite
```

ULS logs show:

```
The feature 'f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa' depends on feature 'aebc918d-b20f-4a11-a1db-9ed84d79c87e' which failed to activate: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The web being updated was changed by an external process. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The web being updated was changed by an external process.<nativehr>0x81020097</nativehr><nativestack>OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000F8529)
at 0x000007FDA9458529 OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000002C021)
at 0x000007FDA938C021 Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000CE89B)
at 0x000007FDA9AFE89B Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000002B48B97)
at 0x000007FDAE038B97 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000002AAD7CE)
```

Comment: its look like publishing feature is not being activated....did you apply any CU /updates on sharepoint farm? what is the result from Central admin?

Comment: Thanks @WaqasSarwarMCSE for your feedback. Found the answer - CMSPublishing#0 is designed to be used as a template for a sub site in a site collection where Publishing Infrastructure is already enabled.

Answer (score 1):

CMSPublishing#0 is designed to be used as a template for a sub site in a site collection where Publishing Infrastructure is already enabled. Credit goes to [Paul S](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/11c9b7c6-72a9-4c11-a83b-799ccb809903/creating-site-collection-with-cmspublishing0-template-fails?forum=sharepointadmin).